# PHP/HTML - How to create a record on a html table like 'orientation rotate text up on excell'

Tags: php, html, css

I have some record on database like this :

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+--------+--------+------------+---------+----------+------+
| NAMA_TYPE           | NAMA_ITEM                | DAMAGE | REPAIR | REMARKS    | MANHOUR | MATERIAL | AC   |
+---------------------+--------------------------+--------+--------+------------+---------+----------+------+
| Cleaning            | Certificate              | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Cleaning            | Interior                 | 01     | 31     | ACETONE -  |    0.00 |    70.00 |      |
| Cleaning            | Exterior                 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Cleaning            | Foreign Marking          | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Under Side               | 01     | 30     | Test       |    0.01 |     0.01 |      |
| Frame               | Left Side                | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Front End                | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Right Side               | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Rear End                 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Top Side                 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Ladder                   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
| Frame               | Walkway                  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL       |    NULL |     NULL | NULL |
+---------------------+--------------------------+--------+--------+------------+---------+----------+------+
```

Now with php, execute it with query and store them into a variable named `$detail`.

I grab it and display on html and the result is suitable like table above. This is the code.

```
 <table cellpadding ="1.1" width="100%">
    <tr style="border:0">
        <th align="center">Type</th>
        <th align="center"style="width:14%">Item</th>
        <th align="center" style="width: 5%">Damage</th>
        <th align="center" style="width: 5%">Repair</th>
        <th align="center" style="width: 40%">Remarks</th>
        <th align="center">Manhour</th>
        <th align="center">Material</th>
        <th align="center">A/C</td>
    </tr>


    <?php
    foreach ($detail as $row) {
        echo "<tr style='border:0'>";
        echo '<td style="border-right:0; border-left:0;">' . $row->NAMA_TYPE . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->NAMA_ITEM . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->DAMAGE . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->REPAIR . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->REMARKS . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->MANHOUR . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->MATERIAL . "</td>";
        echo '<td>' . $row->AC . "</td>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

My question is, please see on Name Type field. Is ist possible to display `cleaning` just once with vertical display but still stretch based the count of the item like this

```
+----------+------------------+ 
|NAMA TYPE |     NAMA ITEM    |
+----------+------------------+
|     C    | Certificate      |
|     L    | 
|     E    |------------------+
|     A    | Interior         |
|     N    |------------------+
|     I    | Exterior         |
|     N    |------------------+
|     G    | Foreign Marking  |
+----------+------------------+
|     F    | Under side       |
|     R    |------------------+ 
|     A    | Left Side        |
|     M    |------------------+ 
|     E    | Interior         |
|          |------------------+ 
|          | Exterior         |
|          |------------------+
|          | Foreign Marking  |
+----------+------------------+
```

Which is `cleaning` is like rotate -45 degrees ('like orientation rotate text up in excell'). Any help it so appreciated.

Anyone ?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Use `rowspan`

Do your loop like so..

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($detail as $row) {
    echo "<tr style='border:0'>";
    if($i==0) echo '<td rowspan="'.count($detail).'" style="border-right:0; border-left:0;">' . $row->NAMA_TYPE . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->NAMA_ITEM . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->DAMAGE . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->REPAIR . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->REMARKS . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->MANHOUR . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->MATERIAL . "</td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row->AC . "</td>";
    $i++;
}
```

And for making the text vertical, see here: https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text